# What is causing the padding/white space inside this div?

Tags: html, css

I want the red border to be tight around the blue text (e.g. no whitespace). What is causing the whitespace and how do I remove it?

```css
#propertyDetails .display_address {
 font-size: 1.75rem;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #3498db;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="propertyDetails">
<div class="display_address">Test Address</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to adjust the width ? or remove the white space from the top line and bottom line?

Comment: @Nasco.Chachev - I want to remove the white space from the top and bottom line

Comment: I don't see any white space, at least at the left of the text, which is what is normally addressed by your margin+padding properties. For the rest, do you mean you want no space under and beneath text? Then it depends on `line-height`. Or even at the right of the text? Then you should use `float: left;`, but it has implications on the whole context...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `line-height:16px;` if that's not compatible with your screen, adjust the pixels.

Answer (score 0):

The `line-height` is what is causing it. Make it equal to 1, which is relatively 100% of the `font-size` so that in the event of different `font-size`, you don't need to change the `line-height` again.

```css
#propertyDetails .display_address {
 font-size: 1.75rem;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 1;
 color: #3498db;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="propertyDetails">
<div class="display_address">Test Address</div>
</div>
```